# Prevent await from blocking async function from going on || Python

Tags: python, asynchronous

So I have an async function which calls another function which should never end but I want function one to move on.

```
async def funtion2():
    #do stuff
    await function2():

async def function1():
    #do stuff
    await function2()
    #do more stuff
```

In this sample "do more stuff" will never happen because function2 never ends, how do I still make "do more stuff" happen?

I tried building loops to avoid this but those either failed due to the same problem or the maximum recursion depth.

Comment: just add it to an executor ... and don't await it

Comment: How would I do that?

Answer (score 0):

```
async def funtion2():
    #do stuff
    await function2():

async def function1(loop):
    #do stuff
    loop.create_task(function2())
    # do more is now hit

if __name__ == "__main__":
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run(function1(loop))
```

Is one way you could add it to the currently running event loop